# NSLayoutConstraint in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to convert the following code to Swift:

```
leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                              relatedBy:0
                                                 toItem:self.view
                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                             multiplier:1.0
                                               constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:leftConstraint];
```

Can someone give me the new syntax to do it in Swift?

Answer (score 31):

Copy & paste from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLayoutConstraint/constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:):

```
convenience init(item view1: AnyObject!,
            attribute attr1: NSLayoutAttribute,
         relatedBy relation: NSLayoutRelation,
               toItem view2: AnyObject!,
            attribute attr2: NSLayoutAttribute,
      multiplier multiplier: CGFloat,
                 constant c: CGFloat)
```

So your code translates to

```
let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, 
                                   attribute: .left, 
                                   relatedBy: .equal,
                                      toItem: self.view,
                                   attribute: .left, 
                                  multiplier: 1.0, 
                                    constant: 0.0);
self.view.addConstraint(leftConstraint);
```

**Code updated for Swift 4.**

Comment: Not relatedBy:0, is now relatedBy:.Equal,

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
var leftConstrains:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

self.contentView.addConstraint(leftConstrains)
```