# UIView in NSLayoutContraint does not conform to AnyObject in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have found this question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460382/nslayoutconstraint-in-swift) however I get the error

```
Type 'UIView!' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
```

for

```
...
@IBOutlet var mainView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
...
NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, ...`
```

Is there somthing happening with dereferencing the view object?

Comment: can you show where do you get the UIView! variable?

Comment: updated question, its declared as an outlet.

Comment: this is really weird. your code compiles with no errors for me

Comment: I really have no idea why it isnt working the only thing i notice in `NSLayoutConstraint(item` is an AnyObject while `toItem` is an Anyobject? is there something funny happening here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was getting the same error after copy-pasting and trying to modify some Objective-C code into my swift project. I realized that I had left relatedBy as 0 instead of NSLayoutRelation.Equal. After fixing that the error went away. Weird that the compiler would show the error on the first parameter when it was really an issue with the relatedBy. Hope it helps.

Comment: Worth mentioning that a typo will also cause this error message.  I had `.Equals` instead of `.Equal` and was getting the error above.

Comment: Thanks rdmurphy and Charles A. for the help. Perhaps were all doing the same tutorial? [link] (http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/?utm_source=maniacdev-ao&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=uiscrollview-autolayout-ios )